# Exclamation sign in data flow execution

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dataflow

Does anyone know what the exclamation sign means next to data flow execution?

However, main execution result is ok.

I appreciate your help in advance.

See screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AGa6.png)

Comment: Does anything happen if you click or hover the icon?

Comment: Nope. I can't find icons related documentation in Microsotf either.

Comment: @DavidLayton I check my data flow execution, it's a "tick" icon.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no documents talk about the icon. But if the pipeline/data flow execute state is "Succeeded", it will be "√" icon.

[image]

[image]

Not very sure why you get the exclamation icon. Just from your screenshot, it seams that you pipeline/data flow works well.

Maybe the exclamation icon it to mention you that your steps could be optimized.

If your want to get exactly meaning of the icon, the best way is that ask [Azure support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). It takes some money and time to get the answer.

As normal users, If the pipeline/data flow works well, all the data is transferred correctly, we could ignore it.

HTH.